# how to get text out of p tags in python using scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

```
<div class="date_info">
   <p>
      <span> Start Date :</span> October 8, 2017 <br/>
      <span> End Date  :</span> October 11, 2017  <br/>
      <span>  Time  : </span> 1:00 pm   to 12:15 pm 
   </p>
   <p> 
      <span> Phone :</span> 507 266 6703  <br/> 
      <span> Email :</span> CVCME@mayo.edu 
   </p> 
</div>
```

how to get October 8, 2017 textvalue from above code? I tried this code :

```
response.css('div.date_info p:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(1)::text').extract()
```

But I'm getting output like this "Start Date".

Can any one help ?

Comment: Typos, style and code highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't insist on using CSS, you can get it with XPath like this:

```
date = response.xpath('//div[@class="date_info"]/p[1]/text()').extract()[1].strip()
```

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, the same using CSS:

```
date = response.css('div.date_info p:nth-child(1)::text').extract()[1].strip()
```

Comment: @Linhart..it worked...Thank you so much...just want to know..cant we get that through using CSS?

Comment: See the edit. I just prefer using XPath as IMHO it's much more powerful tool.

Comment: but in the same way i tried for to get "October 11, 2017". by applying code "response.css('div.date_info p:nth-child(1)::text').extract()[2].strip()"..i'm getting o/p like this ' '..pls help me to get "October 11, 2017"..

Comment: For that you need to supply index `[3]` instead of `[2]`. Take a look what's the result of plain `...extract()` without indexing.

Comment: You're welcome. Just consider accepting the answer so it doesn't hang there unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, notice the `*` operator in `*::text`

```
for div in response.css("div.date_info > p"):
    for span in p.css("span"):
         " ".join(span .css("*::text").extract()) #here you have Start Date and End Date etc
```