# I can't scrape all the contents inside of a video description

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the description of this video : https://www.namasha.com/v/mtlBhvAZ
I can get everything inside the description except for the Telegram link using Scrapy
This is my code :

```
meta_description = Selector(text=response.text).css(
            '#video-desc::text').extract()
```

Comment: Is there even a ::text selector ?

Comment: It must be scrapy specific, looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46663127/14316282). Also from [their documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Comment: Maybe the issue lies in the rest of the code, could you share that with us

Comment: I just have to figure out how to write the selector part ,  if i delete the ::text part i get everything but the html tags also come with it which i dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
telegram_link = response.xpath('//p[@id="video-desc"]/a/@href').get()
```

Comment: This doesn't give me the Telegram link in the description , it just gives the Persian text inside of it. I need both.

Comment: @Fadopamine sorry I misread, I edited my answer.